# Transform a Weibull distribution into a straight line in Python with Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, weibull

The CDF of the Weibull distribution is

```
CDF(x) = 1 − exp[−(x / λ)^k]
```

The CCDF and my approach:

```
CCDF(x) = 1 - CDF(x)
CCDF(x) = 1 - (1 − exp[−(x / λ)^k])
CCDF(x) = exp[−(x / λ)^k]
```

Assuming the following value of scale/k and taking the natural log, ln:

```
k = 1, 

ln(CCDF) = ln(exp[−(x / λ)^k])
ln(CCDF) = -xλ
```

Which yields a straight line with slope -λ.

Code:

```
x3 = np.linspace(1,15, 1000)
weibull_cdf = scipy.stats.weibull_min.cdf(x3, c = 1, scale = 1)
weibull_ccdf = (1 - weibull_cdf)
weibull_ccdf = np.log(weibull_ccdf)
```

Is this implementation solid? Would changing the scale so that scale/k = 2 change the implementation?

Comment: Instead of all that, you could use `weibull_min.logsf(x3, c=1, scale=1)`.  `sf` is the *survival function*, which is the same as the CCDF.  The SciPy distributions include the method `logsf` to compute the log of the survival function.

Comment: Thanks Warren. I was working from a text that did not refer to the docs. Always check the docs...